# inflate a view without XML in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-inflate, android-runtime

first of all, please any one can tell me is it possible to inflate a view without XML ?

Description is like this:
I have dynamically generated a view hierarchy by coding, like

```
Relative layout contain 4 Linear layouts
-1st Linear Layout contain Image View
-2nd Linear Layout contain surface view
-3rd Linear Layout contain Button
-4th Linear Layout contain Text Box
```

and there is no issue in generating all view / view hierarchy (I tested by debugging and inspecting child views)
But I am not able to set it as a setContent()
Because I don't have XML and not allowed to use XML(not sure why), i.e. I have no access of **R.Layout.** So I cant use inflater.Inflate(R.Layout...)
When I am setting main relative layout as a content, I am getting following error

`12-16 11:32:03.653: E/AndroidRuntime(22564): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.package.class}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1d97b`

Anyone have any idea ?
----Updated Log----
`12-16 12:33:16.143: E/AndroidRuntime(25358): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 12:33:16.143: E/AndroidRuntime(25358): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.package.class}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1d97b
12-16 12:33:16.143: E/AndroidRuntime(25358):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
12-16 12:33:16.143: E/AndroidRuntime(25358):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
12-16 12:33:16.143: E/AndroidRuntime(25358):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
12-16 12:33:16.143: E/AndroidRuntime(25358):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
12-16 12:33:16.143: E/AndroidRuntime(25358):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
12-16 12:33:16.143: E/AndroidRuntime(25358):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
12-16 12:33:16.143: E/AndroidRuntime(25358):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
12-16 12:33:16.143: E/AndroidRuntime(25358):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 12:33:16.143: E/AndroidRuntime(25358):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-16 12:33:16.143: E/AndroidRuntime(25358):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
12-16 12:33:16.143: E/AndroidRuntime(25358):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-16 12:33:16.143: E/AndroidRuntime(25358):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-16 12:33:16.143: E/AndroidRuntime(25358): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1d97b`

hope it might help you to understand a bit more
---Dropbox link of my activity class which generate views---
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vclymo0cs0zp360/ScannerActivity.java?dl=0

Comment: Couple of questions: 1. Why can't you define your views in xml 2. Can you post your code on how you are creating and setting these views?

Comment: "I am getting following error" -- if you want help with this, you will need to edit your question to include the full stack trace and the code involved in creating the layout. We have no means of helping you otherwise with this.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for reply, I updated my original question with full logcat and source file is attached..FYI, my activity is extending **CaptureActivity** which is from 3rd party jar library and it is setting that layout from abstract methods..

Comment: You will have to get your support from the author of that `CaptureActivity`, whatever it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is it possible to inflate a view without XML ?

No. The **definition** of the term "inflation" in Android is to convert an XML resource file into a corresponding tree of Java objects. Layout inflation converts an XML layout resource into a corresponding tree of `View` objects.

> But I am not able to set it as a setContent()

I do not know what `setContent()` method it is that you are referring to. To put a `View` as the main content of an `Activity`, [use `setContentView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29).

Comment: aah that was just typo mistake, I mean it setContentView()

Answer (score -1):

There is something wrong with your xml layout thats why you are not able to access R.layout, do Build-->clean and see if there is any error in your xml layout or post your xml here.

Comment: OP is specifically looking to inflate "without XML", so the xml cannot have something wrong since it doesn't exist.